# Fairy's wings material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

How can i achieve a fairy's wings material similar to this one when they glow (i'm using cycles).Thank you [image]

Comment: How far have you got? The solution will be multi layered. Is the result animated of still?

Comment: @rob 1 It's still.I'm just a bit confused on what should i do.

Comment: If the final image is not animated then you can do all sorts of things to fake cool lighting and reflections. I would break the task down. Get the model right and add transparency. Then look at the input sharpness node. You can mix gradients and other patterns to create all the affects and finally use the compositor to add the glare. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

There are a few ways this can be done.

The way I would go with is to draw the pattern of the wings in Photoshop/Gimp and use that as a bump map on a glass shader.

Another way that I did above is to make a base shape for your wing.

Subdivide it 4 or 5 times, apply it, then go into sculpting mode and sculpt the wing pattern (better than I did).

Then use the node set up above.

You can just use a glass shader with an emission shader in the volume, I used 3 different colors for the emission shader and mixed them with a noise texture to break up the colors.

For the glass shader I added a transparent with a layer weight node as a mix factor just so I can hide the glass and make it a little more magical.

If you use the node set up above, play with the noise texture settings and the colorramp flags to clamp what you see.

The multiply (math) node is there just to make the emission brighter or darker.

You can play with the roughness value of the glass shader too, It looks like here wings are a little bit frosted.

Comment: comments cleared to prevent a flame war.